# React Native actionable push notifications with background mode

Tags: ios, react-native, push, react-native-push-notification

I'm making an application with react native init on iOS. Faced with problem that i cant fetch any url or set up socket connection via socketcluster client when app is in background.

Im using actionable notifications (react-native-notifications https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications), rn 0.57.7.

When i make an action in that notification when app is in background - app hangs until ill open it. Seems like a synchronious operation. Making reply, everything goes ok, but stops everytime. When i make an app in foreground - code continues to work. I checked all permissions and capabilites in Xcode, but no effect, still cant post request or connect to socket when in background. What can i do with that situation. Thanks.

Comment: Please note your tag mentions react-native-push-notification, which is actually this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification not the wix one.

Although I have a feeling the wix one is perhaps better?

Comment: @IonicBurger This package is better than Wix's one according to the repo stars and weekly downloads